# Why isnt the the link to working in my js.erb file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I have this in my js.erb file

```
var cart_item = "<table id='something' style='width:100%'>"; 
cart_item += "<tr><td>";
cart_item += "<%= @contact.name %>";
cart_item += "<%= link_to_remote 'Delete', :url => {:controller => 'registrations', :action => 'destroy' %>";
cart_item += "</td>";
cart_item += "</tr></table>";

$("#cart").append(cart_item);
```

and it just hangs but when i comment out the link_to_funtion everything works great. I even tried to make this a link_to and it still hangs and does nothing ....am i missing something

Comment: the cart_item string doesnt get appended to the #cart with the link_to_function as it should with this call $("#cart").append(cart_item);

Comment: You should update your question to include the version of Rails you're working with.  link_to_remote was deprecated a while back - although you can get it included via the prototype_helpers gem

Answer (score 3):

Extract all of that to a partial, call it `_cart_item.html.erb`:

```
<table id='something' style='width:100%'>
<tr><td>
<%= @contact.name %>
<%= link_to 'Delete', {:controller => 'registrations', :action => 'destroy', :id => @contact.id}, :remote => true %>
</td>
</tr></table>
```

Then, your `js.erb` file will look like this:

```
$("#cart").append(<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "cart_item")) %>);
```

But Ryan Bigg is still right, you should:

- use RESTful routes and route helpers.
- use `:remote => true` for AJAX requests, as I've done.
- make sure you're passing an `id` to the `destroy` action so it knows which object to destroy.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of extracting some parts to a partial it worked for me. Using ruby in js.erb is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Four things.

One: No need for the `:url` option. You can just pass the hash as the second argument to `link_to_remote` and it'll work.

Two: You should use the URL helpers for this. Also, if you're using the `destroy` action you'll probably want to pass through an id. This means that you would do something like this instead:

```
link_to_remote 'Delete', registration_path(id)
```

You would be doing something like `resources :registrations` for this. Although, not sure what registrations *are* within your application, so I can really advise on this.

Three: most importantly, you're missing the end curly bracket for the hash on the `link_to_remote` line. This would raise a syntax error if you left it out.

Four: `link_to_remote` is deprecated in Rails 3.0. You should use `link_to 'Delete', registration_path(id), :remote => true`

Comment: I think its more related to the link or something in a js.erb....i changed the line to this for testing and still the same results  -----------  cart_item += "<%= link_to 'Remove', root_path %>";